# Why is this margin here?

Tags: html, css

I am making a profile card and I made div(.pic) in div(.profile-card) to let user show their profile photo.
and i found weird margin at the right of the .pic
Do you know why?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #40407a;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-card {
  background-color: #2c2c54;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pic {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #33d9b2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="profile-card">
    <div class="pic">

    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <span>Name here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Each element has  default margin. You are able to remove it.

Comment: Using `margin: auto;` on `.pic` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `margin: auto;` to have it in center.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #40407a;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-card {
  background-color: #2c2c54;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pic {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #33d9b2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="profile-card">
        <div class="pic">

        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <span>Name here</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have aligning issue. I added this into `.profile-card`

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #40407a;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-card {
  background-color: #2c2c54;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.pic {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #33d9b2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="profile-card"  style="justify-text: center;">
        <div class="pic">

        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <span>Name here</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```